# Python - Problems creating a list of URLs using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a Python Crawler using BeautifulSoup, but I receive an error that I am trying to write a non-String or other character buffer type to a file.  From examining the program output, I found that my list contains many items that are None.  In addition to having None, I also have a lot of images and things that are not links but are image links inside of my list.  How can I only add the URLs to my list?

```
    import urllib
    from BeautifulSoup import *

    try:
        with open('url_file', 'r') as f:
            url_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
            f.close()
        with open('old_file', 'r') as x:
            old_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
            f.close()
    except:
        url_list = list()
        old_list = list()
        #for Testing
        url_list.append("http://www.dinamalar.com/")


    count = 0


    for item in url_list:
        try:
            count = count + 1
            if count > 5:
                break

            html = urllib.urlopen(item).read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
            tags = soup('a')

            for tag in tags:

                if tag in old_list:
                    continue
                else:
                    url_list.append(tag.get('href', None))


            old_list.append(item)
            #for testing
            print url_list
        except:
            continue

    with open('url_file', 'w') as f:
        for s in url_list:
            f.write(s)
            f.write('\n')


    with open('old_file', 'w') as f:
        for s in old_list:
            f.write(s)
```

Comment: Are you trying to filter out everything that is not a string?

Comment: No, I'm trying to filter out everything that is not a real URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, use [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) not the no longer maintained *BeautifulSoup3*, your error is because not all anchors have hrefs so you are trying to write *None* which causes your error, use *find_all* and set *href=True* so you only find anchor tags that have a href attribute:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup.find_all("a", href=True)
```

Also never use blanket except statements, always catch the errors you expect and at least print them when they do occur.  As far as *I also have a lot of images and things that are not links* goes, if you want to filter for certain links then you have to be more specific, either look for the tags that contain what you are interested in if possible, use a regex `href=re.compile("some_pattern")` or use a css selectors:

```
# hrefs starting with something
"a[href^=something]"

# hrefs that contain something
"a[href*=something]"

# hrefs ending with  something
"a[href$=something]"
```

Only you know the structure of the html and what you want so what you use is completely up to you to decide.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Also, I unfamiliar with what you mean by a blanket except statement.  Does that mean that I am just catching some unspecific exception without doing anything about it?

Comment: @VishalVenkataraman What I believe he means is that you should be excepting a specific error. Such as `ImportError` or `FileNotFoundError`, not just the very general `Exception`.

Comment: I know how to do it in java, but how do you catch exceptions in Python?

Comment: @VishalVenkataraman, as Mr.goosberry said catch the specific exception(s), use `except FileNotFoundError as e:print(e)` if you just want links that have a http or https scheme use `"a[href^=http]"` but if the paths are relative you may miss what you want. Only you know what you want, there should be enough information in the answer to figure out how to get it.